# How to access the Rails controller from a liquid tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I want to be able to render Rails' CSRF stuff on a liquid template. I found two pages that give me some clues:

- http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159806314/custom-tags-in-liquid
- https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/blob/v2.0.0.rc12/lib/locomotive/liquid/tags/csrf.rb

My problem is that the thoughtbot link does not explain how to get register the controller in the first place. Then, looking at the locomotivecms source, I can see that the [template is registered with a new context](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/blob/v2.0.0.rc12/app/helpers/locomotive/content_types_helper.rb#L67), but this is done in the helper. I don't think this approach would be appropriate for me because I want to be able to just call the tag `{% csrf_meta_tag %}` in my `.liquid` file.

Is my approach possible? If I am on the right track, how would I then always register the controller along with the context? If I'm not on the right track, how can I go about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem and I found the solution.
Using [this code](https://github.com/locomotivecms/engine/blob/v2.0.0.rc12/lib/locomotive/liquid/tags/csrf.rb), you can add theese tags to your template:

```
{% csrf_meta %}
{% csrf_param %}
```

[Reference](http://doc.locomotivecms.com/references/tags/misc/csrf-param)