# exposing application controller for rails liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid, ruby-2.0

I have a bunch of session stuff which gets set in the application controller which I'd like to be available for liquid.

For example I have an @edition instance variable in the application controller which tells me which particular part of the website they are currently using from the model Edition which has various cities.  The documentation talks a lot about Model based methods, but what about controller based methods/settings?

How can I build a liquid method to read these application controller settings.

```
class Edition < ActiveRecord::Base

def city
end
```

Application Controller something like:

```
  def set_edition
    if session[:current_edition].blank?
      case request.domain(tld_length = 2)
      ...
      else
        edition = 'london'
      end
      session[:current_edition] = edition
    end
    @edition ||= Edition.find(session[:current_edition])
  end
```

I just need a couple of pointers in the right direction as to how I could accomplish this.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the Rails controller from a liquid tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437242/how-to-access-the-rails-controller-from-a-liquid-tag)